# How does android change the height of canvas

Tags: android, canvas

I used to think Canvas.clipRect() method can change canvas's height, but It doesn't.

```
Log.i(TAG, "getWidth:" + canvas.getWidth()); //getHeight: 914
boolean result = canvas.clipRect(200, 200, 400, 400);
Log.i(TAG, "getHeight:" + canvas.getHeight()); //getHeight: 914
```

But a TextView in LinearLayout can do this.

```
<com.example.test.MyLinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.example.test.MyTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="test" />
</com.example.testdatepicker.MyLinearLayout>
```

MyLinearLayout:

```
protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Log.i(TAG, "getHeight:" + canvas.getHeight()); //getHeight: 914
    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
}
```

MyTextView:

```
protected void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    Log.i(TAG, "getHeight:" + canvas.getHeight()); //getHeight: 38
    super.draw(canvas);
}
```

After I read the ViewGroup.dispatchDraw() method, I can't find where does android change the height of canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my question is wrong. The source code I read is android 2.2, and I run it on an android 4.1 device.

I use a monitor run android 2.2, the height of canvas NEVER changed.